# Parametrización consulta SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Buen día,

Estoy quitando las consultas concatenadas, por consultas que sean parametrizadas para evitar cualquier inyección en mi SQL Server, quisiera saber si este INSERT está correctamente parametrizado, así ya puedo seguir una guía de como hacerlo, ya que soy un poco nuevo con esto.

```
                cls_general myCls_general = new cls_general();

                myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");

                mysqlcommand_insert.Connection = myCls_general.myConnection;


                 mysqlcommand_insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Contactos ([IdContacto],[TipoContacto],[CUITCUIL],[CUITFiscal],[RazonSocial],[DNI]" +
                ",[Nombre],[Apellido],[Nacionalidad],[FechaDeNacimiento],[ClaveFiscalAFIP],[CUITAGIP],[ClaveAGIP],[ClaveARBA],[Descripcion],[Condicion])" +
                " VALUES (@contacto_id,@tipo_contacto,@cuit,@cuit_fiscal,@razon_social,@dni,@nombre,@apellido,@nacionalidad,@fecha_nacimiento,@clave_fiscal" +
                ",@cuit_agip,@clave_agip,@clave_arba,@observaciones,@condicion)";

                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contacto_id", txt_cod_contacto.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_contacto", cbo_tipo_contacto.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuit", txt_cuit_cuil.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuit_fiscal", txt_cuit_fiscal.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@razon_social", txt_razon_social.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dni", txt_cod_dni.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", txt_nombre.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellido", txt_apellido.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nacionalidad", cbo_list_paises.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_nacimiento", dtp_fecha_nacimi.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clave_fiscal", txt_clave_fiscal_afip.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuit_agip", txt_cuit_clave_agip.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clave_agip", txt_clave_agip.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clave_arba", txt_clave_arba.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@observaciones", txt_observaciones.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@condicion", cbo_condicion.Text);

                mysqlcommand_insert.ExecuteReader();

                myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();
```

Anexo como está formada mi clase para conectarme a mi base de datos y demás funciones, si hay algo que pueda mejorar y me puedan indicar, seria de gran ayuda, me gusta cumplir con las buenas practicas de programación para poder tener el sistema lo mejor pulido posible.

```
SERVIDOR = "127.0.0.1";
        USUARIO = "sa";
        CONTRASEÑA = "admin";
        BD_01 = "BASE01";
        BD_02 = "BASE02";

        if (basedato == "1")
        {
            myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + SERVIDOR + "; User Id=" + USUARIO + "; Password=" + CONTRASEÑA + "; Initial Catalog=" + BD_01 + "; Pooling=False;");

            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        if (basedato == "2")
        {
            myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + SERVIDOR + "; User Id=" + USUARIO + "; Password=" + CONTRASEÑA + "; Initial Catalog=" + BD_02 + "; Pooling=False;");

            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public void cerrar_conexion()
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }

    public void sqlcommand(string strSQL)
    {
        try
        {
            int Filas = 0;
            SqlCommand msSqlcommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, myConnection);
            Filas = msSqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    public DataSet sqlcommand_select(string strSQL)
    {
        //Retorna un dataset
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter Adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myConnection);
            Adaptador.Fill(dataSet);
            return dataSet;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return dataSet;
    }
```

Comment: A priori tienes pequeñas cosas que pulir. No deberías de insertar directamente datos extraídos de lo que ponga el usuario en un textBox sin pasar por una validación. fecha_nacimiento, dtp_fecha_nacimi.Text El usuario no tiene porque saber ni ser capaz de poder dar un formato a una fecha. contacto_id, txt_cod_contacto.Text Lo mismo. deberías de pasar este valor antes de llegar a la insert por un int Try Parse. El comando no es un ExecuteReader sino un ExecuteNonQuery. También puedes pensar en utilizar bloques using para abrir y no tener que cerrar y disposar la conexión

Comment: Me puedes dar un ejemplo básico? Aunque sea algo breve.

Comment: Te explico un poco más como es mi modulo. El usuario no tiene acceso al formato de la fecha ni al código de contacto. Al dar clic en el botón de añadir un nuevo contacto, tengo una tabla de contadores, donde consulta el ultimo y le suma el siguiente. Pero el usuario no tiene acceso a este textbox ni a la fecha. Uso devexpress, lo que capturo en el campo de texto de la fecha, es la fecha seleccionada.

Comment: En mi clase me conecto a mi base de datos de la siguiente forma (ver mi pregunta.)

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo en base al tuyo. Lo más importante es que cierres los recursos después de utilizarlos, porque si por algo falla por ejemplo el método sqlcommand o el sqlcommand_select no se eliminan los recursos, aunque si le des salida al mensaje por pantalla. Pero esos recursos continúan abiertos.

```
public DataSet sqlcommand_select(string strSQL)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        var ConnectionString = getConection();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            //Inicializa el comando que se va a ejecutar
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, connection))
            {
                //Se agregan los parámetros
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PKEY", PKEY);
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Se abre la conexión
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 900000;
                        cmd.Connection.Open();
                        //Se cargan los datos en el DataTable
                        da.Fill(ds);
                    }
                    catch (SqlException sqlEx)
                    {
                        //trata el error como te parezca más adecuado por ejemplo en un archivo de log.
                        string error = sqlEx.Message;
                        return null;
                        // si lanzas la excepción al emisor, este podrá presentarlo al cliente. (messageBox.show)
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        } return ds;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //trata el error como te parezca más adecuado por ejemplo en un archivo de log.
        
        throw e; 
    }
}
```

Si observas la diferencia, radica en que los bloques using, se "cierran/disposean" ellos solitos al terminar, independientemente de que el código haya generado una excepción del tipo que sea.

Para usar sqlcommand como lo tienes, debes de plantear una sobrecarga o un nuevo método que utilice los SqlParameters

```
public void sqlcommandWithParams(string strSQL, SqlParameter []misParams)
{
    try
    {
        int Filas = 0;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, myConnection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(misParams);


                Filas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
public void sqlcommandWithParams(string strSQL, SqlParameter[] misParams)
{
    try
    {
        int Filas = 0;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, myConnection))
            {
                foreach (SqlParameter param in misParams)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                }

                Filas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Esto puede ser una aproximación a, como puedes y debes mejorar el código.

No trates los errores (msgBox.show) en las clases que usas para consultar datos. Devuélveselos al formulario que ha pedido los datos, y desde donde haces la llamada, preséntalo al cliente como prefieras.

**Nota adicional**: mysqlcommand no es un buen nombre, porque existe otro conector para otro SGBD, que se llama mySqlcommand y por tanto algún día te puede dar un susto el intellisense, o cuando compartes código, puede llevar a equivocaciones.

Comment: Vale, más o menos entiendo el ejemplo, estoy tomando un desarrollo existente y mejorandolo poco a poco. Si yo parametrizo mi consulta como fue la pregunta original, quiere decir que si yo no modificio mi clase principal de conexión, sigue estando mal? Si en vez de usar using, hago lo siguiente:

Comment: `mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@observaciones", txt_observaciones.Text);
                mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@condicion", cbo_condicion.Text);

                mysqlcommand_insert.ExecuteReader();

                mysqlcommand.dispose()

                myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();`

Es valido o algo similar hacer el dispose() asi?

Comment: Una insert, no es ExecuteReader() sino ExecuteNonQuery(), ya que no lees nada. Por otro lado, si es válido que un objeto del tipo SqlCommand impelmente el método dispose ya que hereda de IDisposable. Pero si ocurre una excepción en el código, tienes que ejecutarlo igual en un catch, siempre que el objeto no sea null [SqlCommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) y si te da una excepción el cierre de la conexión también lo hay que hacer.